# How to integrate a progress bar in a pandas iterrows for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, progress-bar

I acknowledge that using iterrows in pandas is bad practice, but this is what I'm dealing with from previous projects leftovers...

I am using a for loop like so to iterate through a pandas data frame for some data manipulation (on mobile so forgive my poor formatting) -

```
for index, row in df_temp.iterrows
# do stuff
```

I've since wanted to wrap a progress bar feature around this loop to track its progress (given the amount of data it consumes). I have found something like tqdm but its use case is rather simplified, is there a neat way to restructure my for loop so that a progress bar feature can be slotted in?

Tried simply taking a counter of the loop and keeping track of that during each iteration, but that seems counter-intuitive..

Comment: Use [tqdm](https://tqdm.github.io/): `for index, row in tqdm(df_temp.iterrows): # do stuff`. Note though, that `.iterrows` is usually slow and should be avoided.

Comment: good call, yeah it is pretty painful seeing this thing iterates through a humongous dataframe, but it's out of my hands atm regarding alternate approaches.. Thanks!

Comment: IIRC, an `.apply(lambda x: func(x.name, x), axis=1)` is an edge faster than iterrows; don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(10_000,))

for index, row in tqdm(df.iterrows()):
    # do stuff
    row
```

[image: example output]

Answer (score 0):

`iterrows` is an iterator so tqdm does not know its length. You can pass the value of the length to the `total` parameter as follows -

```py
for _, row in tqdm(df.iterrows(), total=df.shape[0]):
```

Then you will actually see the progress bar.